# Why Can't I Parent My Armature to My Mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature, parent

I've tried selecting my mesh, then my armature (correct order) and hitting Ctrl+P, and selecting "With Automatic Weights", and in the content panel it moved my mesh under the armature. But it gave me an orange message with "Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones", and the mesh didn't deform with the bones in Pose Mode.

What am I doing wrong?

(I tried to add a GIF picture, but it says the recording is too large to upload.)

Comment: Delete any loose vertices or non-manifold things in your mesh and try again.

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to take this down, though, since there was already another question that gave an answer that worked for me? (I don't want to clog up the path to answers, or waste answerers' time.)